# Add spaces to first line and another amount of spaces to all other lines

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a file where i need to put 7 spaces for the first line and 3 spaces for all the other lines.

So i did this (i put 1d to ignore the first line) :

```
sed -i '1 s/^/       /' $f
sed -i '1d s/^/   /' $f
```

It works for the first line spaces but the other one gives me this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command
```

Comment: Regarding the error, you need to use `;`, `-e` etc to separate multiple commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '
  # more spaces for the first line
  1s/^/              /
  # less spaces for all the other lines.
  1!s/^/   /
'
```

You can learn sed at https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-25 https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html .

You could also do like subtraction, add 4 spaces on first line and then 3 spaces everywhere. `1s/^/    /;s/^/   /`